# How to handle error in router using middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node & express to make a server
but for some reason the error occurring in a router does not get handled & crashes the entire server:

Server.js:

```
import SubRouter from './routes/SubRouter.js';
import express from 'express';

const server = express();
server.use(express.json())
server.use('/sub', SubRouter);

server.get("/update", (req, res) => { 
    throw new Error("Testing") // This does not crash the server
});

// Handle Error
server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error("Error Handled")

    res.json({
        error: err.message
    })
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`listening at 3000 ...`);
});
```

./routes/SubRouter.js:

```
import { Router } from "express";

const SubRouter = Router()

SubRouter.get("/update", async (req, res) => { 

    throw new Error("Testing") // This crashes the server

});

export default SubRouter
```

Error Log:

> ```
> file:///.../routes/SubRouter.js:7
>     throw new Error("Testing") // This crashes the server
>           ^
>
> Error: Testing
>     at file:///.../routes/SubRouter.js:7:11
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at /.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
>     at Function.process_params (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
>     at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
>     at Function.handle (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
>     at router (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
> ```

I would use a `try catch` but that defeats the purpose of having an Error handler middleware

Can someone please explain why the error is not getting handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, The problem wasn't with router it was with `async` so I wrapped my function with an `asyncHandler` like this:

```
SubRouter.get("/update", asyncHandler(async (req, res) => { 

    throw new Error("Testing") // This no longer crashes the server

}));
```

where `asyncHandler` is defined as follows:

```
const asyncHandler = func => (req, res, next) => {
    func(req, res, next).catch(next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally wrap the code that may produce an error in `try...catch` block. When an error gets caught, I pass it to the error handler route using `next(error)`.

To use the `next` callback function, you need to add another parameter to your routes as shown below:

```js
SubRouter.post('/update', (req, res, next) => {
  ... any code that wont produce error
  try {
    ... any code that might produce error
  } catch(error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});
```

This way you make sure all errors thrown inside your routes are caught by your error handling middleware. To improve this approach, I create a helper class which handles errors and produces more meaningful errors to pass to error handling middleware.

```js
// helpers/ErrorHandler.js

class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor(message, status) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.name = 'HTTPError';
  }
}

class InternalServerError extends HTTPError {
  constructor(message) {
    super('Internal server error occured.' + message, 500);
    this.name = 'InternalServerError';
  }
}

class InvalidUserCredentialsError extends HTTPError {
  constructor() {
    super('Invalid user credentials provided.', 400);
    this.name = 'InvalidUserCredentialsError';
  }
}

class ErrorHandler {
  static handle(error) {
    if(error instanceof InvalidUserCredentialsError) {
      // you can warn the user about invalid login attempt or whatever
    }

    if(error instanceof HTTPError) {
      // log error to file, db or console
      return error;
    } else {
      // log internal server error differently
      return new InternalServerError(error.message);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  HTTPError
  InvalidUserCredentialsError,
  ErrorHandler
};
```

After that you can use these custom errors in your routes as such:

```js
const { InvalidUserCredentialsError, ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/ErrorHandler.js');

SubRouter.post('/update', (req, res, next) => {
  // let's assume user tries to login here and provides invalid credentials
  try {
    ...
    if(invalidCredentials) {
      throw new InvalidUserCredentialsError();
    }
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    return next(ErrorHandler.handle(error));
  }
});
```

This is my own approach and it works pretty much fine. You can also outsource the error messages into another file such as `messages/errors.js`. So you can manage error messages in single file and multi-language them easily when needed.

Comment: nice solution but I still don't understand why the server crashes? I mean it didn't crash when the path was not in a router like in post `/update`

Comment: I really don't know why server crashes when you reach to `/sub/update`, but doesn't when reaching to `/update`. Can you provide some error log?

Comment: I've updated the question to reproduce a minimal example and also added error log